# How do I run PHPUnit tests?

Tags: testing, 9

Having just kind of gotten my head around Simpletest functional testing in Drupal 8.x, I've now started trying to use PHPUnit testing since Simpletest has been deprecated in Drupal 9.1.x.

I started by looking at the instructions on [Running PHPUnit tests](https://www.drupal.org/docs/automated-testing/phpunit-in-drupal/running-phpunit-tests). However, when I get to [the step on running the tests](https://www.drupal.org/docs/automated-testing/phpunit-in-drupal/running-phpunit-tests#s-running-tests) I get this.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Drupal\Tests\node\Functional\NodeTestBase" not found in /opt/drupal/web/core/modules/node/tests/src/Functional/PagePreviewTest.php:22

This looks a bit like an autoload issue to me. I ran the following command to verify it was effectively so.

```bash
php -r "require_once('autoload.php'); var_dump(class_exists('\Drupal\Tests\node\Functional\PagePreviewTest'));"
```

The command outputs *bool(false)*.

My knowledge really ends here. The documentation seems to be moot on this, and it looks like I'm not the only one with this problem. (See [How to run PHPUnit tests?](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/installing-drupal/2020-07-02/how-to-run-phpunit-tests)).

How do I run PHPUnit tests?

This is the Docker file content that can be used to reproduce what I described in the question.

```
FROM drupal:9.1.0

RUN composer require -n \
  phpunit/phpunit:9.5.0 \
  phpspec/prophecy-phpunit:2.0.1 \
  symfony/phpunit-bridge:5.2.1

RUN cd web/core; phpunit -c phpunit.xml.dist modules/node/tests/src/Functional/NodeTestBase.php
```

Building this causes the error I described above.

Comment: You're using the core **dev** version `9.1.x-dev`, right?

Comment: @NoSssweat I'm using [9.1.0 docker image](https://github.com/docker-library/drupal/blob/c9f287f02d7c12ec7c1f89e4ed43005f5e90a7ef/9.1/apache-buster/Dockerfile) for testing. Should I be using the dev version?

Comment: `core/modules/node/tests/src/Functional/NodeTestBase.php` doesn't exist?

Comment: @anonymous yes the file exists. I've added a dockerfile to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is that you are using the sample `phpunit.xml.dist` instead of copying it to `phpunit.xml` and then making a few teaks for your installation.

Part of the `phpunit.xml` file is setting up the autoloader to find test classes and modules (they are not in the normal autoloader). And you tend to get some really weird errors if you don't set up the DSN for the database (to run Kernel and Functional tests).

I would do the following (adjust paths as needed ; I'm looking at a core-dev project right now and not a live site).

- In your install, do `composer require --dev drupal/core-dev:~9.1.0`. You may want to tweak the version number, depending on you you have core defined.
- Make sure you are running the binary from `vendor/bin` in your install.  I suggest looking into [direnv](https://direnv.net/).
- Copy `phpunit.xml.dist` to `phpunit.xml` and edit

  - `SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL`
  - `SIMPLETEST_DB`
  - `BROWSERTEST_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`
    to reflect your installation.

Then cd to `core`, and run

```
../vendor/bin/phpunit -c phpunit.xml --testsuite unit
```

This should start to loop through the Unit tests. Abort that if they look like they are working, and then do

```
../vendor/bin/phpunit -c phpunit.xml --testsuite kernel
```

Then, if that looks OK you can start to run your own tests.

All of that said, it is much easier to run individual tests through PhpStorm. You just need to got through the preferences to point to the right PHP interpreter, and set a few things for phpunit.

In your case, it may be better to just start the `drupal:9.1.0` container, and then shell into it for initial testing before updating the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: Drupal.org has also documentation for running DrupalCI on a local computer. While it uses Vagrant instead of Docker, would it be a "easier" way of testing Drupal core and modules and be able to reproduce the output the tester runners on Drupal.org give?

Comment: @apaderno What I described is essentially what I use for core development. I haven't found an advantage for Docker/Vagrant or full DrupalCI locally. I have a bunch of shell scripts for running tests, and if need all that DrupalCI does it is because I need a full testbot run and don't want to do that locally (though I have been toying with setting up a Pi4 Branble to do it).